# TortoiseGit: Access denied

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a problem with tortoiseGit. When I use clone, pull or push in tortoise it always reports "acces denied". But if I use the console it works without problems.

I tried reinstalling git/tortoiseGit but it doesn't help.

this is from tortoiseGit:

```
git.exe clone      --progress -v  "ssh://mavl@rcs.tmapy.cz:7722/var/lib/git/    NavisIZS2014" "D:\work\workspace\IZS2014\NavisIZS2014"

Cloning into 'D:\work\workspace\IZS2014\NavisIZS2014'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (2016 ms @ 25. 11. 2013 9:17:24)
```

and when I use console:

```
D:\work\workspace\IZS2014>git.exe clone      --progress -v  "ssh://mavl@rcs.tmapy.cz:7722/var/lib/git/NavisIZS2014" "D:\work\workspace\IZS2014"
Cloning into 'D:\work\workspace\IZS2014'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Comment: How are you authenticating?

Comment: Please tell us: what exactly did you do, what was the exact error message you got? The question right now has too little information to help. Also, please read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Probably with Tortoise you're using a different user than on console...

Answer (score 4):

Since you are authenticating via ssh, it's likely that Tortoise Git cannot find your ssh keys.

You can specify the key path in Toirtoise Git by navigating to

Settings > Git > Remote

and setting the Putty Key field, as [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/198614).

Answer (score 2):

1. Update TortoiseGit.
2. SEt connection in updateed Tortoise. Settings - Network - SSh - SSH client. Set new TortoisePlink.exe through Browse.
3. Try again.